# Creating a custom kickstart file for cobbler and fedora installation

Tags: linux, kickstart, cobbler

I am trying to write a custom kickstart file for use with cobbler in automating installations across the network. I am having some issues understanding the kickstart file and wondered if anyone knows of a resource that clearly explains the options to use and what they do when creating the file?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [article in the Fedora wiki](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Anaconda/Kickstart) is probably one of the largest sources of information on kickstart options.

Update: this wiki has been moved to the [pykickstart](https://github.com/rhinstaller/pykickstart/blob/master/docs/kickstart-docs.rst) repo on GitHub.

Comment: Using that page and the auto-generated kickstart at /root/anaconda-ks.cfg is how I first got started.

Comment: Thanks very much this is exactly what I was looking for.